# Get derived type from static method

Tags: c#, reflection, types, static

I want to get derived type from static method.

I want to do something like this

```
void foo()
{
  this.getType();
}
```

but in static method

I know that

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
```

returns base type, but i need derived.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example?

Comment: BTW, "sth" is not an English word, nor is it an accepted abbreviation of the word "something".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you mean you have something like this

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(/* current class name */);
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

and want `MyDerivedClass.DoSomething();` to print `"MyDerivedClass"`, then the answer is:

There is no solution to your problem. Static methods are not inherited like instance methods. You can refer to `DoSomething` using `MyBaseClass.DoSomething` or `MyDerivedClass.DoSomething`, but both are compiled as calls to `MyBaseClass.DoSomething`. It is not possible to find out which was used in the source code to make the call.

Comment: I think FxCop or ReSharper complains if it catches you calling a static method on a derived class -- as in "are you sure you know what's going on here?"

Comment: So, I propably should use Generic, and try to get typeof(T), or maby u know any better way to do this?

Comment: You could pass the type to the method: DoSomething(Type derivedStaticType) and then work with this type inside of DoSomething (also checking if it is indeed derived from MyBaseClass). A bit ugly but it works.

Comment: In java you can get the calling class through a stacktrace hack, I don't think this would be possible in C# though.

Comment: Over the years so much nonsense has been added to the language which is making a big mess of everything but not really anything, to the point that one needs to set very strict guidelines of what can be used internally, but things like this which are needed are left in the backlog...

Answer (score 12):

I guess you need something like this scenario:

```
void Main()
{
  Base.StaticMethod(); // should return "Base"
  Derived.StaticMethod();  // should return "Derived"
}


class Base
{
  public static void StaticMethod()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name);
  }
}

class Derived: Base 
{
}
```

This code will, however, return

```
Base       
Base
```

This is due to the fact that the static method call is resolved at compile time as a call to the base class, that actually defines it, even if it was called from a derived class. The lines

```
Base.StaticMethod();
Derived.StaticMethod();
```

generates the following IL:

```
IL_0001:  call        Base.StaticMethod
IL_0006:  nop         
IL_0007:  call        Base.StaticMethod
```

In a word, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

7 1/2 years later...

I was wanting to do very much the same thing which is how I found this question.  There is a solution that is close to what is being asked for and *MAY* be useful for others searching this question.

I wanted a static method that would return an instance of the class with all the base settings set for me.  The following works:

```
void Main()
{
    ChildClassA cA = ChildClassA.SetFoo();
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public bool Foo {get; set;}
}

public class ChildClassA : BaseClass
{
    public static ChildClassA SetFoo() => new ChildClassA{Foo = false};
}

public class ChildClassB : BaseClass
{
    public static ChildClassB SetFoo() => new ChildClassB { Foo = false };
}
```

That's all well and good, but I wanted to put that `SetFoo` function in the base class so that

1. I wouldn't have to have so much repetitive code and
2. To ensure all BaseClass objects have `SetFoo`.

You cannot do:

```
    public abstract static BaseClass SetFoo;
```

because something that is static cannot be abstract.  You also cannot do:

```
    public static BaseClass SetFoo => new BaseClass{ Foo = false };
```

because you can't new up an abstract class.

What you CAN do, though, is use generics to specify the derived type you want.  That would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    ChildClassA cA = BaseClass.SetFoo<ChildClassA>();
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public bool Foo {get; set;}
    
    public static T SetFoo<T>() where T:BaseClass, new() => new T{Foo = false };
}

public class ChildClassA : BaseClass
{
    // You can leave this here if you still want to call ChildClassA.SetFoo();
    //public static ChildClassA SetFoo() => new ChildClassA{Foo = false};
}

public class ChildClassB : BaseClass
{
    //Again, you can leave this for ChildClassB.SetFoo()--the compiler won't mind
    //public static ChildClassB SetFoo() => new ChildClassB { Foo = false };
}
```

This is only a little more clunky than what we really wanted (derived.StaticBase), but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

As you alluded to in a comment, it is possible using generics.  Running this - say in LinqPad - will produce 'MyDerivedClass'.

```
void Main()
{
    MyDerivedClass.DoSomething();
}

abstract class MyBaseClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass<T>
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}

class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass<MyDerivedClass>
{
}
```